# Get original file path from JSP <type="file"> to Spring Boot Controller

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, jsp

I'd like to get an original file path from the JSP page to Spring BOOT Controller

Here is, i am doing on JSP Page

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/">
  <table>
    <tr><td>File to upload:</td><td><input type="file" name="file" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></td></tr>
 </table>
</form>
```

Controller.java

```
public void save(MultipartFile file) {
  
//want selected original file here 
 
  }
```

**if i select file from "E:\OEC\test\", then a want same file path in Spring boot controller**

Comment: Note that due to security settings you might just get a "fakepath" from the user's browser.

Comment: @Thomas I have tried that way and I got the same fake path as you said

Comment: Well, that's the point: the browsers will not send the real path unless that's allowed in their security settings. So there's nothing you can do on the Spring end of things.

Comment: @Thomas well there has to way to access the local file path from the JAVA script or Spring boot

Comment: I'll repeat: it is a _security_ issue so unless the browser's settings (which the user might change) allow for accessing and sending the real path it cannot be sent to the server so Spring Boot has no chance there. Any Javascript running in the browser should be subject to the same security settings so the browser might not make that path available here. Of course that doesn't mean the path is unknown as the browser itself needs to know, it just doesn't tell you (much like I can provide information without revealing the source ;) ).

Comment: Here's the official source: https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#file-upload-state-typefile (look at example 15 in section 4.10.5.1.17). Quote: `For historical reasons, the value IDL attribute prefixes the file name with the string "C:\fakepath\". Some legacy user agents actually included the full path (which was a security vulnerability).`